# The reason why Cannot access empty property ?

Tags: codeigniter

I'm new to this...help me please

$data is object

```
stdClass Object ( [menu_id] => 38 [menu_code] => M062 [menu_name] => BAP (RICE) [price] => Rp 6.364 [total] => 1
```

and $fields is array, this is not all..

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [code] => menu_id [title] => ID [width] => 5 ) [1] => Array ( [code] => menu_code [title] => Kode [width] => 8 ) [2] =>
```

and this is my function :

```
function writeRowAsli($row, $startChar, $fields, $data){
    $i=$startChar; $j=''; $k='';
    foreach($fields as $field){
        $k = $j.$i;
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($k.$row, $data->$field['code']);
        $last = $k;
        if($i == 'Z'){
            $i='A';
            $j.=$i;
        } else $i++;
    }
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($j.$i.$row, '=SUM(C'.$row.':'.$k.$row.')');
}
```

i know the bad line is $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($k.$row, $data->$field['code']);
thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Change your function as below and check if its work or not:

```
function writeRowAsli($row, $startChar, $fields, $data){
    $i=$startChar; $j=''; $k='';

    $fields = array_filter($fields);

    foreach($fields as $field){
        $k = $j.$i;
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($k.$row, $data->$field['code']);
        $last = $k;
        if($i == 'Z'){
            $i='A';
            $j.=$i;
        } else $i++;
    }
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($j.$i.$row, '=SUM(C'.$row.':'.$k.$row.')');
}
```